# Node MYSQL How can I get a joined table in its own object?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm currently using this SQL query:

```
var sqlQuery = `
    SELECT user.ID, user.email, user.first_name, user.last_name,
    user.address1, user.address2, user.country, user.gender, chars.sID, chars.name,
    chars.experience, chars.locked  
    FROM subscriber AS user 
    LEFT JOIN chars on user.ID = chars.sID
    WHERE user.ID = ?
`;
```

Which works fine and I get this style of result:

```
RowDataPacket {
[1]     ID: 13,
[1]     email: 'fakeemail@email.com',
[1]     first_name: null,
[1]     last_name: null,
[1]     address1: null,
[1]     address2: null,
[1]     country: null,
[1]     gender: null,
[1]     sID: 13,
[1]     name: 'CharName',
[1]     experience: 0,
[1]     locked: 'N' }
```

The only problem is that I get that result for every `chars` in the database, I only need the subscriber once and then I need the many `chars`

But how can I get it so I end up with something like

```
RowDataPacket {
    field: blah,
    field: blah,
    charData: {
        name: 'CharName',
        locked: 'N'
    }
}
```

I want the joined data to be in its own object. Any information would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql always return raw array. If you want something like that, you need to format it to your needs.
There are some libaries that can help you like `lodash`, but it's not hard task

You can solve it by go for all the rows in the array and add it to another object
The other object `result` will have keys the email of the subscriber, and array of charsData.

For Example:

```
 result={
    'subscriber1@gmail:{
        'field: blah,
        field: blah,
        charsData: [{
            name: 'CharName',
            locked: 'N'
            },{
                name: 'CharName2',
                locked: 'l'
        }]
    },
    'subsriber2@yahoo':{
        Another Subscriber
    }
}
```

---

**The Code:**

```
var result={}
var input=YourArrayFromMySQL

for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
    var thisLine=input[i]

    //Copy the char to new variable
    var thisChar=   {
            name:thisLine.name,
            locked:thisLine.locked
                }

    //Delete the char from the subscribe line               
    delete thisLine.name
    delete thisLine.locked

    //If this subscriber not exsists in the result, create it, with empty array
    if(!result[thisLine.email]){
        result[thisLine.email]=thisLine
        result[thisLine.email].charsData=[]
    }

    // Add to the matching subscriber the char
    result[thisLine.email].charsData.push(thisChar)
}
```

Comment: Seems hacky, but thanks I'll mark as answer unless something else comes a long.